# Bind ALT key in Tmux to move across panes

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I would like to bind `ALT + <hjkl>` in tmux to move across splits.

I've seen this [**plugin**](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator) that allows you to move across panes with `CTRL + <hjkl>` but I would like to keep the `CTRL + l` shortcut for clearing the terminal.

I've also tried putting the settings in `.tmux.conf` myself but the problem in ubuntu is the `ALT` key shows the menu and that seems to interfere with what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What desktop environment are you using? Unity? Can't you disable the menu function in the keyboard settings? That's usually one of the first things I do on a new desktop environment.

Comment: Yeah, unity. I've gone through the settings but it's not there.

Comment: It's normally in Keyboard -> layouts -> options under "Behavior of Alt/Win" or something similar. Alternatively, run `dconf-editor` and look for something like `activate-window-menu`. For my Cinnamon, it's under `org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.wm`. Is that set to `Alt`?

Comment: I think that would be the HUD shortcut key. I've already disabled that one. I've checked the settings already, I can't seem to find where it is.